# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database, authentication

Trying to connect to a vm hosted mysql server through workbench. Testing the connection gives me this error.

What Ive tried:

- re-creating my user and re-granting privileges, and flush.

**a.k.a.**

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'homeIP' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

- setting mysql path variable on windows.
- nothing added to my.cnf except max_allowed_packet.
- adding 'skip-grant-tables', causes it not to connect at all
- I am certain the password I'm entering is correct.
- SELECT user, host FROM mysql.users; shows the  expected names and IPs.
- SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'homeIP', shows that all privileges are granted.

Comment: Why the `mysql_native_password` option?

Comment: `'username'@'homeIP'` and `username@'%'` are different users; you have a password for one and privileges for the other. It's easy to think that '%' is a superset of all `username` accounts, but that's not how MySQL rolls.

Comment: @Jerry so does than mean I should create another user called {username@'%'}, and give it privileges, and it will be accessible from my home network?

Comment: After creating username@'%' and granting privileges, it connects. Still a little confused on the why though. If anyone can explain.